# GWT - Using a Checkbox as the header of a DisclosurePanel

Tags: gwt, checkbox

I'm trying to create a DisclosurePanel that uses a Checkbox for a header. However, when I set this up, clicking on the Checkbox only opens and closes the DisclosurePanel; it doesn't check or uncheck the box. Anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add handlers to the open / close events and set the value of the checkbox there:

```
disclosurePanel.addOpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>(new OpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {

  @Override
  public void onOpen(OpenEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
    checkbox.setValue(true);
  }
));

disclosurePanel.addCloseHandler<DisclosurePanel>(new CloseHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {

  @Override
  public void onClose(CloseEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
    checkbox.setValue(false);
  }
));
```